# ¿Cómo se puede lidiar con usuarios nuevos que crean muchas cuentas?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Buen día,

En las últimas semanas me he dado cuenta que hay varias peguntas similares y al ver los nombres de usuario son casi iguales por lo que he llegado a creer que es la misma persona preguntando varias veces con el fin de "llegar" a más usuarios

¿Existe alguna forma en que Stack Overflow detecte usuarios con múltiples cuentas?

¿Qué podemos hacer los usuarios normales en caso de sospecha sobre uso indebido? Ya sea spam o boost de cuentas (A veces se votan con sus otras cuentas para ganar reputación)

Comment: SO se encarga de avisar por procesos automaticos ( y magicos  ;) ) sobre usuarios con multiples cuentas. Lo otro, si avisan, los mods lo podemos chequear...

Comment: dudo que el usuario cambie de VPN cada vez que crea una cuenta nueva por lo mínimo si un usuario crea mas de 2 cuentas desde a misma IP ya eso es un flag para el sistema automatizado ...

Comment: Eso que dices es llamado [sock puppeting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuenta_de_usuario_t%C3%ADtere).